# Permissions to use preview and Experience editor

Tags: sitecore-client, editor-user-permissions

I am trying to set up a user profile to only allow someone to add items to one page on our site. I seem to have almost everything configured correctly, but for some reason the below error happens anytime they use preview or experience editor. Is there a special permission that needs to be given to access these features? Logging in with other user accounts those features seem to work just fine, so I am led to believe it's something within the user privileges. Running Sitecore 8.
[image]